# Unable to install PHP 7.0 with Ubuntu 14.04.02

Tags: php, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I executed the commands:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

And the ouput

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main php-common all 1:49+deb.sury.org~trusty+4
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/ trusty/main php7.0-common amd64 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  404  Not Found
```

..................
   ..................

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/php7.0-fpm_7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
```

The repository has different packages, i can see in "http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php7.0/" that versión 7.0.15 is missing

How can i change local source to download 7.0.31 instead?
Thanks

Comment: ppa:ondrej/php is working now.